# my setInterval functions are slowing down my code-how can I rework it for better performance?

Tags: jquery, performance, setinterval, lag

I've written some code that uses moment.js and some jquery to pick the right jpeg at the right time from a big folder and then iterate through them.

I used setInterval to get the speed right (500ms between images) and it was working at that speed consistently until I realized I needed to account for some leading zeros in the jpg filenames (they are generated with six digits e.g. 000001.jpg up to 100000.jpg) and so I added in a function pad () that I found to correct for that.

Problem is I've noticed that the pad function running every 500ms is really slowing things down..there's no reason I need to run the pad function more that frequently-- for example at the speed I'm loading the jpegs (500ms), I only need the pad function twice in the first 5000ms (at 000001.jpg and then at 000010.jpg) and after that the necessary frequency goes down exponentially (e.g. nothing needs to be done again until 000100.jpg which is ~45000ms later, etc...)

But since the pad function manipulates variables that are called within the 500ms setInterval event, I can't figure out how to separate that part out to improve performance. Any ideas?

Here's my laggy code:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="three/js/moment.js"> </script>
    <script src="three/js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  <style>
    .frames { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
    .frames img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
  </style>
  <head>

  <body>
    <img id = "frame_placeholder">

    <script>

      now = moment().zone('-0500')

      if (now.hour() >= 18) {
        now = now.subtract('hour', 18).subtract('minute', 30)
      } else {
        now = now.add('hour', 6).add('minute', 30)
      };

      var frame = ((now.hour() * 3600) + (now.minute() * 60) + now.second()) * 2;




     window.onload = $(function (){
      setInterval(function() {
          var framestr=frame.toString();
                                function pad (str, max) 
                                {
                                  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
                                }; 

          framerun = pad (framestr,5);

          var src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/image/"+ framerun +".jpg"

          framerun1=parseInt(framerun)
          $("#frame_placeholder").attr("src", src);
          frame=framerun1+=1;

       },500);  
      });






    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't need to define pad function every interval , start by moving the function  declaration out

Comment: true. i tried that but when i moved it out my code stopped working, and I got stumped about why. i figured it made more sense to show you all what it looked like when it worked but i could edit it to show you how i tried to move the pad function to a slower setinterval? would that be more helpful?

Comment: A better way to pad: `framerun = ("0000000000" + frame).substring(-6)`

Comment: Anyway, the there is nothing inherently "slow" with how the code is written (and the placement of the pad function *does not matter*) - even the pad provided will run on O(n) time. Now, perhaps there is a degenerate DOM interaction with setting src?

Comment: you might consider preloading images into array also...and then just loop over array of already loaded images

Comment: @user3079080 Also, remove `window.onload =`. That bits confusing and has no beneficial effect. (The act of `$(function () { .. })` itself sets up the appropriate ready handler.)

Comment: @user3079080 And, can you post a http://jsfiddle.net case so I can play with it? xD

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GunGu/

Comment: @LJ_1102 Doesn't seem to run slow here.. src is updated every half-second (granted all the image-loads are unauthorized for me)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to redefine the pad function every interval run,
define it in window scope and only use it in the interval callback.

The same goes with the jQuery matching, match the element once and store it in a variable.

```
var $frameholder = jQuery('#frame_placeholder');
```

Also spaces around the equals sign in attribute definitions are invalid.

```
id = "frame_placeholder"
```

should be

```
id="frame_placeholder"
```

EDIT:
Also be sure to use parseInt always with the radix parameter to avoid conversion errors due to wrong guessed number system.

```
parseInt(framerun, 10);
```

Comment: The location of the pad function is largely irrelevant to the execution speed. It should be mentioned, perhaps, but not to such a point that makes it sound like the issue. Likewise, caching the element is nearly irrelevant as it runs so infrequently - the timer runs at most twice a second.

Comment: This is true, its propably not the performance issue, but its still not "irrelevant" since its better code style, I'm setting up a fiddle right now to investigate further.

Comment: It's not relevant to the problem. It's a secondary topic.

Comment: interesting that it might not be the cause of the lag. I was pretty sure it was all I changed between versions when I started noticing the problem, but I'm going to go back to the "faster" version and double check...

Comment: I've created a fiddle of your original code and analyzed it but cant see any performance problems in Chrome. Maybe you just need to restart your browser, worth a try i guess? Also just asking, if you're changing the image every 500ms how are your users supposed to load it that fast? If you want to do animations you'll be way better of preloading the frames and draw them to a canvas or using gifs.
http://jsfiddle.net/GunGu/

Comment: I think you guys are right-- it's not a pad problem, the slow down I get when I test it happens even when I remove the pad function. Each image is quite small (30k) so I figured 2 per sec wasn't that taxing...but maybe I'm going to have to figure out some way to do a sort of slideshow with a buffer